# Best practices on setting exit status codes

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code

When implementing my own scripts, is it the best practice to exit with different exit codes for different failure scenarios? Or should I just return exit code 1 for failure and 0 for success providing the reason on stderr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing a descriptive error message to stderr is fine and well for interactive users, but if you expect your scripts to be used by other scripts/programs, you should have distinctive error codes for different failures, so the calling script could make an informed decision on how to handle the failure.

If the calling program does not wish to handle different failures differently it could always check the return code against `> 0` - but don't assume this is the case.

Comment: I agree. 0 is always OK, positive numbers are used as errors and negative numbers as warning. Like that, a caller can decide whether to check for non-zero (there was an error or a warning) or greater-zero (there was an error). For the value of the exit code there is this (for me rather strange) behavior of "IF ERRORLEVEL n" in Windows batch programming to consider which returns true if n is equal to or less than(!) the error code returned by the application. Hint: "IF %ERRORLEVEL%==n" does only return true if there is an exact match.

Comment: I just realize that it must be opposite: Warnings must be greater than zero and errors negative values - then the "IF ERRORLEVEL n" makes sense: 0 is also true if the exit code was 10 but not if it was -10.

Answer (score 2):

There are some recommendations, see wikipedia, but not normative, except the one of 0 iff success:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX

*In Unix and other POSIX-compatible systems, the wait system call sets a status value of type int packed as a bitfield with various types of child termination information. If the child terminated by exiting (as determined by the WIFEXITED macro; the usual alternative being that it died from an uncaught signal), SUS specifies that the low-order 8 bits of the exit status can be retrieved from the status value using the WEXITSTATUS macro in wait.h;[6][7] when using the POSIX waitid system call (added with POSIX-2001), the range of the status is no longer limited and can be in the full integer range.

POSIX-compatible systems typically use a convention of zero for success and non zero for error.[8] Some conventions have developed as to the relative meanings of various error codes; for example GNU recommend that codes with the high bit set be reserved for serious errors,[3] and FreeBSD have documented an extensive set of preferred interpretations.[9] Meanings for 15 status codes 64 through 78 are defined in sysexits.h. These historically derive from sendmail and other message transfer agents, but they have since found use in many other programs.[10]*